# Can't I say 'Anytime' in reply to a 'Thanks' from my manager?

Tags: colleagues, work-experience, india, manager

There was a small issue at work. I solved it and notified my manager over IM. She said, 'Thanks, Vinay'. I replied her, 'Anytime' as I do with my other colleagues and friends.

A colleague of mine sees this conversation while working along with me on the issue and gets surprised and says, 'Anytime!? Even to our superior!?'

Another colleague advises me not to repeat this again and tells that weren't supposed to say that way.

I'm confused. Is it really something important from my superior's perspective? Will this give the wrong impression? If it's so, what would be a polite way to reply other than a formal 'Welcome'?

Comment: I put this on hold since it's generating poor answers based on unsubstantiated opinion. It's not that this is a bad question, just that it's not a good question for our Q&A format. To get this reopened, the answers would need to be vastly improved and be backed with facts, references, and experiences that demonstrate the answer is correct.

Comment: @jmort253 A good note and wise decision. It's really opinion based. Thanks for the community users and Elliott's answers.

Comment: @jmort253, This answer **can be answered objectively** if we look at it from a broader perspective (as opposed to focusing on Vinay's situation). Many many people have this question too, "polite way to reply thanks from superiors".

Comment: @Pacerier, you're welcome to [edit] the post if you think it can be clarified, and then create a post on [meta] to see if we can get support for reopening it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My suggestion is to say, "My pleasure," in lieu of, "Anytime," because this infers that you actually enjoy the task at hand. [Politeness is a valuable skill in the workplace](http://senoritaruth.com/archives/10827), just as it is in everyday life. In the study of [politeness theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politeness_theory), value is placed on not being imposing. By saying a task or chore is a pleasure literally means that it is [enjoyable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pleasure), which is quite the opposite of something being imposing.

[Jane Mairs, Editor at Merriam-Webster](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/blog.php?action=ViewBlogArticle&ba_id=263) summarizes,

> "My pleasure" is an idiomatic response to “Thank you.” It is similar to "You’re welcome," but more polite and more emphatic.

For more opinions on the matter of politeness when it comes to responding to a, "Thank you," head over [to english.stackexchange.com and read over this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42697/different-ways-to-say-youre-welcome).

Comment: Hello Elliott, welcome to The Workplace. On our site, we're looking for expert answers with some depth that explain *why* and *how*. Our goal is to build a library of knowledge for navigating the professional workplace. Please consider an [edit] to expand. See [answer] for details.

Comment: @jmort253 Thanks for the note. I accepted your challenge and improved my answer. Hopefully this will be beneficial to the asker and the community.

Comment: Great answer, Elliott! See http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14070015#14070015

Comment: I think your answer is outstanding.  This has made me reconsider how I respond to people.